# how to display the month in from view ? (Odoo11)

Tags: python, odoo

please, how do I display the month in the form? example:
07/04/2019 i want to change it in 07 april, 2019 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try with following steps:

- Go to Translations > Languages
- Open record with your current language.
- Edit date format with %d %A, %Y

Comment: Great. You can accept answer. So other users can get help for same issue. Thank you.

Comment: @Navi You don't need to get these in code. If you do configuration as per above answered, it will display your desire format.

Answer (score 2):

@Navi asked how to do it in the code so here are 2 way to do it:

If you want to get this in the code, you can edit the file `odoo/addons/base/data/res.lang.csv`

You can also update it in the code with

```py
self.env['res.lang']._lang_get(self.env.user.lang).date_format = '%d %A, %Y'
```

or

```xml
<record id="base.lang_fr" model="res.lang">
    <field name="date_format">%d %A, %Y</field>
</record>
```

However you really shouldn't do it in the code.